# Order of Request and Respond in Express

Tags: javascript, express

In the Express `app.get()` method, is there any difference in what order I write response and request?
I mean between `app.get("/", (req, res) =>` or `app.get("/", (res, req) =>`?

Comment: short answer is "yes"

Comment: Mind giving the long answer? ;)

Comment: You may wait a bit longer and get long winded explanations contest from those, who wish to score some rep. I don't.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it matters what order they are in, because they are *positional arguments*.  Technically you can assign any name though.

`(req, res) =>` is the canonical form.

You could even write

`(request, response) =>`

But if you write `(res, req) =>` then you are accepting the request in a variable called `res` and the response in a variable called `req`.  So, please **don't do that.**  Because coworkers can be vengeful.

Comment: Thank you! I've been following the correct order till now, but I was just unsure if I did it because, "That's just the normal way of doing it", or if it actually get the Request first and the response second.